# Failed to get environment, + java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError, Traceback IOError: File not found -

Tags: java, python, windows, exception

I run windows 7 on a 64bit system.
I use netbeans 6.9.1 (the python plug ins are installed)
Installed also: Python 2.7.1(64), JDK 6 update 24(64),

I'm interested in term extraction so I downloaded montylingua which is supposed to run in Java or/and Python.
this is the link: http://web.media.mit.edu/~hugo/montylingua/

When I try to run the Sample.java code included in the zip file available, I encounter these problems:

```
****** MontyLingua v.2.1 ******
***** by hugo@media.mit.edu *****
Failed to get environment, environ will be empty: (0, 'Failed to execute command ([\'sh\', \'-c\', \'env\']):
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified')

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: Traceback (innermost last):
  File "C:\work\montylingua-2.0\copy\JMontyLingua.py", line 0, in __init__ 
  File "C:\work\montylingua-2.0\copy\MontyLingua.py", line 0, in __init__ 
  File "C:\work\montylingua-2.0\copy\MontyLemmatiser.py", line 0, in __init__ 

IOError: File not found - 
    at org.python.core.Py.IOError(Py.java)
    at org.python.core.PyFile._setup(PyFile.java)
    at org.python.core.PyFile.<init>(PyFile.java)
    at org.python.core.__builtin__.open(__builtin__.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(PyReflectedFunction.java)
    at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(PyReflectedFunction.java)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java)
    at montylingua.MontyLemmatiser$_PyInner.__init__$5(MontyLemmatiser.java:5312)
    at montylingua.MontyLemmatiser$_PyInner.call_function(MontyLemmatiser.java:5219)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java)
    at org.python.core.PyInstance.__init__(PyInstance.java)
    at org.python.core.PyClass.__call__(PyClass.java)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java)
    at montylingua.MontyLingua$_PyInner.__init__$1(MontyLingua.java:218)
    at montylingua.MontyLingua$_PyInner.call_function(MontyLingua.java:163)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java)
    at org.python.core.PyInstance.__init__(PyInstance.java)
    at org.python.core.PyClass.__call__(PyClass.java)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java)
    at montylingua.JMontyLingua$_PyInner.__init__$1(JMontyLingua.java:85)
    at montylingua.JMontyLingua$_PyInner.call_function(JMontyLingua.java:63)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java)
    at org.python.core.PyInstance.__init__(PyInstance.java)
    at org.python.core.Py.initProxy(Py.java)
    at montylingua.JMontyLingua.__initProxy__(JMontyLingua.java:256)
    at montylingua.JMontyLingua.<init>(JMontyLingua.java:234)
    at montylinguaapplication.MontySample.<clinit>(MontySample.java:8)
Could not find the main class: montylinguaapplication.MontySample.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

I am familiar with Java since I have some small programming experience with it. I know nothing about Python.
I have set the environment variable "MONTYLINGUA" which is necessary for the program to run.

I have seen a post about Jython from somebody who gets the same first error as me, but I was not able to do anything from the things proposed. (the link of the other post: [Jython - javaos.getenv() gives "Failed to get environment, environ will be empty"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245787/jython-javaos-getenv-gives-failed-to-get-environment-environ-will-be-empty))

Anyone who can run this .java file correctly may recommend something.

I can upload the java code also, but I think it is obsolete since it is available and easy to find in the site mentioned...

In the project I included also the JyDT_Update_Site_1.4.15 zip, just in case that this would help, but unfortunately nothing happened.

Maybe I have to add some code in a specific file, like in the case of the other post, but I don't know in which to add what, in my system.

thank you for you time.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the same issue as the one from the post you linked.

> 'Failed to execute command ([\'sh\',
>   \'-c\', \'env\']):
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot run
>   program "sh":

Implies that jython is configured to think it's running on a UNIX system of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to set in the Jython *registry file* the property `python.os`.

You can locate the registry file following these instructions: http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/registry.html#finding.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the python code is trying to run a shell command.
But, since you're on Windows, this does not work.

It makes me wonder if this is really the canonical way to get at the environment in python?

Comment: I changed that 'true' value to 'false' in the registry file of jython (since I have also installed jython). Nothing changes...

Comment: and maybe is about python, and not jython (excuse me if I'm wrong, but I really don't have any idea about how are these two related). Maybe python has a registry file (although I have not find it yet), where I could add some code or change some values....

Comment: the positive thing is that I can run the application in python through the command line without any error, but this does not help me for the purpose I want to use montylingua. In java through the command line goes a bit further than before, but still have "errors": 
 ****** MontyLingua v.2.1 ******
***** by hugo@media.mit.edu *****
Lemmatiser OK!
Custom Lexicon Found! Now Loading!
Fast Lexicon Found! Now Loading!
Lexicon OK!
LexicalRuleParser OK!
ContextualRuleParser OK!
Exception in thread "main" Traceback (innermost last):
  File "C:\work\montylingua-2.0\copy\MontyLingua.py", line 0, in main

Comment: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction can
not access a member of class java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder with modifiers "pub
lic"

Answer (score 0):

You will need the Sun Java compiler, version 1.4.2, installed on your system. 
Without it, you will have trouble runningthe MontyLingua Java examples, and 
we are not sure whether you you can compile MontyLingua into a .NET DLL. 
Search www.sun.comfor version 1.4.2 of the Java SE Development Kit and install 
it.